# Why cannot we go in outer space with constant speed?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, free-body-diagram, rocket-science

Sorry if this question is very childish for experts here. This was the question I had in school and years later it has resurfaced. I did some google search but getting the same equations of gravitation.

So I have learned that to escape the gravitational field of Earth and go in outer space the rocket has to be accelerated greater than the gravitational acceleration of Earth i.e. 9.8 m/s2.

I am not able to understand as much as I think if I just send a rocket in an upward direction and keep it propelling with a constant velocity even as low as 1 m/s will it not escape gravity and go in outer space. Why does the acceleration constraint there?

Comment: And how do you keep that constant speed?

Comment: And  how do you get to that 1 m/s initially?

Comment: @BillN  FGSUZ assuming somehow with some technology that is achieved...let us accelerate it initially to reach 1m/s and keep it constant with some un-invented technology... won't it escape? I think it will escape.

Answer (score 3):

You CAN go at a constant speed.

In fact, if you apply a force upwards that would make a rocket accelerate at $9.8 m/s^2$ in empty space, when not under the influence of gravity, it WOULD go upwards at a constant speed!

The point is that since the earth's gravity pulls back on objects with that acceleration of $9.8 m/s^2$ (close to the earth's surface at least) you must give that acceleration upwards in order to counteract the earth's gravitational pull and move upwards at a constant velocity, and must give more than that acceleration to actually **accelerate** a rocket upwards.

Comment: OK...if I understand you....you mean to say that the constraint on acceleration is actually a constraint on Force...meaning the greater acceleration means a greater force vector in an upward direction? So if I have a force in upward direction counteracting gravity, even if the velocity upwards is constant, it will go in space?

Comment: If you have a constant force upwards, not only will it go into space, but it will eventually accelerate into space as the distance from the earth grows and gravity weakens. So yes, you can go into space at a constant velocity, and a constant force upwards greater than the gravitational force the earth applies on the rocket will definitely get it into space.

Comment: That's right, Gravity is not constant, it changed with distance (getting weaker).  So with enough force to counter 9.8 when you get high enough you will accelerate away from Earth.  To be truly constant you need the rocket to wind down.  +1

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting confused about the concepts of velocity, acceleration, and force.  If you can somehow maintain a 1 m/s velocity component away from the surface of the earth you can get to "outer space." (There are circular components of velocity that 
real spaceships have to allow for, too. Just trying to address the radial, or to-and-from motion.)

The problem is that there is a **gravitational force**, $\vec{F_g}$, always pulling your ship back toward earth. To initially get to 1 m/s you must provide a **thrust force** in the direction opposite $\vec{F_g}$ and greater than it so that the **net force is away from earth**. Once you get to 1 m/s (or any other speed you want to consider), you still must provide an upward force or gravity will pull the ship back unless your speed is what is called escape velocity. exactly how to calculate that is beyond the scope of your question, but for earth starting near the surface it's approximately 11 km/s.  If you turn your engines off before reaching that speed, you'll not escape earth, but you might orbit.

If you keep providing thrust and maintain an outward velocity of any value, you can escape.  The problem with maintaining thrust is carrying enough fuel to do that. Fuel has mass, and you have to burn fuel to carry fuel with you for burning later. Eventually the fuel is gone and the thrust is gone.

Comment: Sorry to bother you but, I just checked the wiki page for escape velocity and saw the derivation of the equation which I understood but I am not able to visualize this in terms of velocity...that question remains in my head...with the above answer by Jousha I am able to visualize that a force higher than Fg will be needed...I mean an 'escape force' leading later to constant velocity makes sense to me...but an 'escape velocity' is not making sense...why can't we just get to the point of 1m/s and no further and keep moving that ways?

Comment: @XIkkyuX If you throw a ball upwards with a velocity of 1m/s, what happens? The downward acceleration of gravity stops it and then makes it fall down again. If you throw it faster, it will go higher before it starts to fall. If you throw it at the escape velocity (or even faster than that) it will *never* stop and begin to fall back. But if you *continuously* apply a force to the ball, you can make it continue upwards at a constant 1m/s for as long as you keep applying the force.

Comment: @alephzero OK you mean to say that the escape velocity means that the initial velocity that an object should be thrown so that it escapes the gravitational field, and that is the practical implementation we need to send the rocket outside, but in a theoretical scenario 1m/s velocity upwards will do?

Comment: @XIkkyuX to respond to your comment to allephzero: If an upward velocity is **maintained**, that will "send the rocket outside." But that requires something to provide an upward force.

Comment: @XIkkyuX If you understood the **escape velocity** page, what don't you "visualize ... in terms of velocity." I don't understand your comment.  There is no escape force. There is an escape velocity which is the velocity needed at a certain point in a gravitational field which will allow an object to have an "outward" velocity for an infinite distance with no further outward thrust.  If the velocity is less than the escape velocity (at the current location) and the thrust disappears, the ship will eventually stop and move back in the direction of the gravitational field.

Comment: @XIkkyuX Just to emphasize, the escape velocity is the velocity which is needed if there is *no more outward thrust*. If you can maintain a net zero or net outward force (gravity versus thrust), the speed value doesn't matter. Gravity is always present until infinity so you always need some thrust if you're below escape velocity.

Comment: OKkk, now I understood, the key point is that 'the thrust disappears'... in my imagination, I was keeping the rocket thrust constant at escape velocity...now I get it...thanks for the answer...long time brain worm is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Escape velocity calculation is done assuming there is no constant thrust  which keeps on accelerating you. That being said, if you can get some hypothetical device produces enough thrust that you have even 0.00000001 m/s² acceleration or even zero acceleration and move with infinitesimal constant velocity RADIALLY away from the earth, you will enter and move into space